# Why is $\sum_{i,\:j\:\in\:I}\cos(2\pi\langle k,x_i-x_j\rangle)$ small for small $k$ whenever the $x_i$ have a minimum distance to each other?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, exponential-function, fourier-transform, sampling

Let $I$ be a finite nonempty set, $(x_i)_{i\in I}\subseteq[0,1)^2$ and $$f(k):=\sum_{i\in I}e^{-{\rm i}2\pi\langle k,\:x_i\rangle}\;\;\;\text{for }k\in\mathbb Z^2.$$

> Assume $x_i\ne x_j$ for all $i,j\in I$ with $i\ne j$. I want to choose $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ such that they are "uniformly" spread over $[0,1)^2$, but simultaneously satisfy that $|f(k)|$ is "small" whenever $|k|$ is "small". What would be a suitable condition to ensure the latter?

For example, I've read that the latter is satisfied when the $x_i$ have a suitable minimum distance to each other. But how do we see this? Clearly, $$|f(k)|^2=\sum_{i,\:j\:\in\:I}\cos\left(2\pi\langle k,x_i-x_j\rangle\right)\tag1,$$ but how do we see the desired property from this expression?

Consider the trivial case of a regualr grid: Let $m,n\in\mathbb N$ and assume $$x_{ij}=\left(\frac{i+\frac12}m,\frac{j+\frac12}n\right)\;\;\;\text{for all }(i,j)\in I:=\{0,\ldots,m-1\}\times\{0,\ldots,n-1\}.$$ For $m=n=64$ and $k\in\{-256,\ldots,255\}^2$ a splot of $|f(k)|^2$ looks as follows:

[image]

The white dots correspond to the points $x_i$. And for all other $k$, the value of $|f(k)|^2$ is $0$. But how do we see this analytically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $k=(k_1,l_2)$. Then
$$\langle k,x_{i,j} \rangle = k_1\frac{2i+1}{m} + k_2\frac{2j+1}{m}.$$
Applying the function $t \mapsto e^{-i2\pi t}$, one gets the product of a function of $i$ by a function of $j$.

Therefore, the double sum over $i,j$ splits into the product of a sum over $i$ by a sum over $j$. Both sums are geometric sums and can be computed explicitly (separate the cases where $k_1 = 0$ or $k_2=0$).

Comment: Hm ... I see. The regular grid obviously has a minimum distance property between the points. But how do we see the claim in general, i.e. that $|f(k)|$ is "small" whenever $|k|$ is "small"?

Comment: I do not know what does « having the minimum distance property mean ». If the uniform probability measure in $I_m$ tends to the uniform measure on $[0,1]^2$ as in your example, then the associated characteristic functions $f_m$ tend to $0$ over $\mathbb{Z}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: What I mean is that the $(x_i)$ are arbitrary, but $$\inf_{\substack{i\in I\\ j\in I\setminus\{i\}}}\|x_i-x_j\|\ge\varepsilon$$ for some large enough $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: This is not sufficient to ensure that $|f(k)|$ is small whenever $|k|$ is small (but not zero). For example, if you take twice more points (well spread) on the left half than on the right half, it will not work for $(k_1,k_2)=(1,0)$.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is the rather simple algorithm described here: https://blog.demofox.org/2017/10/20/generating-blue-noise-sample-points-with-mitchells-best-candidate-algorithm/. It generates $(x_i)$ by iteratively sampling a number of candidates from a uniform distribution and each time chooses the one which has the maximum minimal distance to the samples generated so far. I wonder whether this can be utilized in the proposal generation for the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm (see my other question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/597768/222528).